# Merge conflict resolved using previous resolution in GIT. What does it mean?

Tags: git

Using the command

`git stash pop`

I got as output

> Auto-merging src/path/File.Java
>
> CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in src/path/File.Java
>
> Resolved 'src/path/File.Java' using previous resolution.

I tried `git status -s`

and the output was

> UU src/path/File.Java

As per the output of `git stash pop` command, 1st git says there is a conflict and then git itself resolved that conflict.

It's bit confusing. How does git managed to resolved conflict itself without any manual intervention ? What happened in the backend ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Resolved+using+previous+resolution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It managed to do so because you have [`git rerere`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere) enabled.

With rerere enabled, it records how you resolve certain conflicts. If Git encounters those again, it resolves them the way the same way as you had resolved them previously.